# Vb.net Interface, make method only accept instances of same type as parameter

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, types

I'm trying to define a method in my vb.net interface that will only accept objects that inherit from the same interface and are also of the same class as the instance which receives the method call. Is this possible in vb.net?

Below I try to illustrate with a (invalid) generic type constraint what I wish to do:

```
Public Interface IFoo

   CompareStuff(Of T as sametype)(obj as T) as Boolean

End Interface
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Interface IFoo(Of T)
    CompareStuff(obj As T) As Boolean
```

Use like this:

```
Public Class Foo Implements IFoo(Of Foo)
    Function CompareStuff(obj As Foo) As Boolean
```

but unfortunately also allows this to compile:

```
Public Class Bar Implements IFoo(Of Foo)
    Function CompareStuff(obj As Foo) As Boolean
```

Can't think of anything properly constraining right now.

Comment: After writing the question I also thought of this way. It comes close but not all the way... :) Is there any way in C# (that could b e translated) to do what I want?

Comment: I don't think C# is any more expressive around this kind of thing; it's just the syntax tends to be shorter :)

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

I'm a little rusty on my VB, so here it is in C#

```
public interface IFoo<T>
    where T : IFoo<T>
{
    bool CompareStuff(T obj);
}
```

Then you implement it like this

```
public class Foo : IFoo<Foo>
{
    bool CompareStuff(Foo obj);
}
```

Check out [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx) about it from Eric Lippert.  Pay special attention to the end where he says:

> My advice is to think very hard before you implement this sort of curious pattern in C#; do the benefits to the customer really outweigh the costs associated with the mental burden you're placing on the code maintainers?

Answer (score 1):

If type `X` derives from type `Y`, and a `Y` can perform some operation upon another `Y`, then the Liskov Substitution Principle requires that a `Y` must be able to perform that same action on an `X`, and also that an `X` must be able to perform that same action on a `Y`.  Putting those requirements together, an `X` must be able to perform that operation upon another `X`.

Note that it would be possible for an `X` to be able to perform some operation on another `X`, without such action being performable by, or upon, a `Y`.

Incidentally, while it's useful to implement `IEquatable<T>` for structures and sealed classes, the question of whether any object is equal to any other can be answered meaningfully for any two objects of any types.  For example, if one has a collection of `Cat`, one may reasonably try to compare the objects in that collection against a parameter of type `SiameseCat` (while the collection may contain instances of `PersianCat`, it might also contain some of type `SiameseCat`) or type `Animal` (some passed-in objects might be of type `Dog`. but others might be of type `Cat`).  While querying a collection of `Cat` to see if it contains some particular `Dog` might be "silly", the collection should have no problem answering the query ("Zero instances found").